# how to delete member from chat room xmpp server via php

Tags: php, android, web-services, curl, openfire

I am trying to delete a member of chat room from XMPP server via php. I am using curl request for that.

I am following this documentation:
https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#delete-a-user-from-a-chat-room

```
$url = "http://188.***.***.***/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms/".$roomName."/members/".$userJID;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/xml", "Authorization : ******")); //I am using plugin.userservice.secret key here
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");    
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
```

It should return me http response 201, but I am getting login form of server in response or 401 (unauthorized user).

I am trying to do this since last one week, but did not get any solution of this till, please help me.

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that this question if very specific: it relates to a specific XMPP server implementation (Openfire) and makes use of a proprietary, non-standard interface (its REST plugin). The fact that you're making use of an Android environment, PHP and/or cURL is irrelevant.

When you receive 401 responses, then there is a problem with authentication.

As Roman points out in a comment below, you're using the wrong documentation. Use [this](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#authentication) instead!

Two other observations that Roman made (out-of-band):

- There's a surplus space character in "Authorization :" It need to be "Authorization:"
- The property that you should use is plugin.restapi.secret, not plugin.userservice.secret.

Comment: You can find the reference here: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#authentication 
The mentioned documentation above was for the mucservice plugin, which is now deprecated.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice the incorrect documentation reference.

Comment: @Guus Thanks for your response, and sorry I am using the same documentation that you have provided. And I have updated the both points you have told me. Now I am getting 302 response and its showing login form of server admin. And you were saying that it is irrelevant to using curl, can you please tell me the proper way to hit those endpoints (that are in documentation, as I am a php developer not an android developer I am creating web services for an app). My need is to just delete a member from xmpp sever (I have created the group and users via curl) any how. Thanks again.

Comment: I think, it might be possible that I need to make some changes on open fire sever, please let me know if any change is needed on sever configuration.

Comment: If you use Openfire 3.9.3 or lower you need provide instead of the JID in the path url the username. Since 3.10 you can also use JID.

Comment: @RomanS. I have also tried with username, but always get the server login form or 401 (unauthorized). And I have come to know that why I am getting 401, if I am not logged in to server on the same browser then it always returns 401. I am so much frustrated did not get any solution yet :(

Comment: Ok. If you will be redirected to the server login, it means your requested URL is wrong or contains chars like ? @.
If you get 401, it means your provided Credentials are wrong provided or simple wrong. Please verify that provided credentials are also configured in Openfire. Such Guus mentioned, you need at first active the plugin, over Openfire > Server Settings > REST API. And set authorization to secret key or http basic auth and provide such credentials

Comment: I have set all these things, my other services are working fine, I am able to create user via the same process (using curl). Just sucked in remove member service. As you said, I am going to reconfigure my xammp server may be my luck will work. I'll respond you the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind supports, finally I have achieved that, the issue was the authorization key. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is already well answered but I will like answer for Android specific context so other user coming to this question can find an alternate way.
There is a library for RestApiClinet for android [here](https://github.com/xibsked/Openfire-Rest-Api-Client-Android). You can integrate it directly as android module. Here is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sked.ofadmin) already using it. You can also have a look on this client library written in [php](https://github.com/gidkom/php-openfire-restapi).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will really help to others :)